# DDD and CQRS - Define an entity for Scheduling use case

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I have a use case of scheduling a person to some work for some time range. Eg. A service for assigning a person A to work for time range X to Z in location C.

The only constraint it has, is one person cannot work on 2 things at same time. Eg. if person A is assigned to work in time 2019-07-21 to 2010-07-25, then person A cannot be assigned to any other work in that time. Eg. Person A for time range 2019-07-23 to 2019-07-27 should not be possible.

I am trying to make a service for it using domain driven design which would assign a person to some work. The entity I thought would be something like:

```
class Assignment {
    PersonId,
    startTime,
    endTime,
    location
}
```

Now, I wanted to make sure that if I found a entry in my database for Person A in some time range, then the call to create an entry for Person A in time range that is overlapping with the existing ones should fail.

Since, I am using CQRS model with DDD, so I don't want to make a query to my database asking for all the assignments for that person. This may not always be recent data because of eventual consistency in CQRS model. 
I know in my primary key, PersonId would be there but I am not sure how can I use start and end time in it.

Any suggestions what I can do to achieve my goal for this? Is doing DDD and CQRS not a good idea in this? Or there is a better way to model this entity so that I can achieve my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to ensure that a single `Person` can not be given more than one `Assigment` for a given time-span is to query for all ranges in which that `Person` is currently assigned work and calculate the invariant. That is, it is a requirement of your invariant that we have full knowledge of the time-spans for all current assignments. Querying your *command side* cannot be eventually consistent or invariants cannot be enforced. Period. That said, there is plenty of room for some optimization here.

The most obvious optimization is to add another invariant: a `Person` cannot be given an `Assignment` with a `startTime` in the past. This will greatly reduce the amount of data with which we are working (the effect is that you will no longer need to *load* any related `Assignments` with an `endTime` in the past).

A second optimization may be to internally "flip" the representation of available time-spans within each `Person`. So instead of storing a list of `Assignment` (unavailable time-spans), we store a list of `UnassignedTime` (available time-spans). Depending on how many `Assigments` you expect each `Person` to have at a given time and what other invariants may exist, the above (or some form of it) may be an option as well.

The last thing I would like to mention here is that this invariant needs to be placed on your `Person` entity (or some other slice of it e.g. `Worker`) because of the reasons outlined in my first paragraph -- whatever entity is *getting* assigned work must have knowledge of all of its current work. Again, depending on the details of your domain, the above makes the existence of the `Assignment` entity as your describe it unsuitable (as it has no invariants that it, itself, can enforce).

At a high level, I would expect the program flow to be something like:

```
// within AssignWorkCommandHandler or SchedulingService method

var person = people.Find(cmd.PersonId);

person.Assign(cmd.StartTime, cmd.EndTime, cmd.Location); // may throw

people.Save(person);
```